# Why can't we assign int* x=12 or int* x= "12" when we can assign char* x= "hello"?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the correct way to use `int* x`? 
Mention any related link if possible as I was unable to find one.

Comment: Arrays and strings http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html  Pointers Dreaded Pointers http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex15.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string literal creates an array *object*. This object has static storage duration (meaning it exists for the entire execution of the program), and is initialized with the characters in the string literal.

The value of a string literal is the value of the array. In most contexts, there is an implicit conversion from `char[N]` to `char*`, so you get a pointer to the initial (0th) element of the array. So this:

```
char *s = "hello";
```

initializes `s` to point to the initial `'h'` in the implicitly created array object. A pointer can only point to an *object*; it does not point to a *value*. (Incidentally, that really should be `const char *s`, so you don't accidentally attempt to modify the string.)

String literals are a special case. An integer literal does not create an object; it merely yields a value. This:

```
int *ptr = 42; // INVALID
```

is invalid, because there is no implicit conversion of `42` from `int*` to `int`. This:

```
int *ptr = &42; // INVALID
```

is also invalid, because the `&` (address-of) operator can only be applied to an object (an "lvalue"), and there is no object for it to apply to.

There are several ways around this; which one you should use depends on what you're trying to do. You can allocate an object:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr); // allocation an int object
if (ptr == NULL) { /* handle the error */ }
```

but a heap allocation can always fail, and you need to deallocate it when you're finished with it to avoid a memory leak. You can just declare an object:

```
int obj = 42;
int *ptr = &obj;
```

You just have to be careful with the object's lifetime. If `obj` is a local variable, you can end up with a dangling pointer.  Or, in C99 and later, you can use a *compound literal*:

```
int *ptr = &(int){42};
```

`(int){42}` is a compound literal, which is similar in some ways to a string literal. In particular, it *does* create an object, and you can take that object's address.

But unlike with string literals, the *lifetime* of the (anonymous) object created by a compound literal depends on the context in which it appears. If it's inside a function definition, the lifetime is *automatic*, meaning that it ceases to exist when you leave the block containing it -- just like an ordinary local variable.

That answers the question in your title. The body of your question:

> What is the correct way to use `int* x`?

is much more general, and it's not a question we can answer here. There are a multitude of ways to use pointers correctly -- and even more ways to use them incorrectly. Get a good book or tutorial on C and read the section that discusses pointers. Unfortunately there are also a lot of *bad* books and tutorials. Question 18.10 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is a good starting point. (Bad tutorials can often be identified by the casual use of `void main()`, and by the false assertion that arrays are really pointers.)

Answer (score 2):

Because the literal "hello" evaluates to a pointer to constant memory initialised with the string "hello" (and a nul terminator), i.e. the value you get is of `char*` type.

If you want a pointer to number 12 then you'll need to store the value 12 somewhere, e.g. in another int, and then take a pointer to that:

```
int x_value = 12;
int* x = &x_value;
```

However in this case you're putting the 12 on the stack, and so that pointer will become invalid once you leave this function.

You can at a pinch abuse that mechanism to make yourself a pointer to 12; depending on endianness that would probably be

```
int* x = (int*)("\x0c\x00\x00");
```

Note that this is making assumptions about your host's endianness and size of `int`, and that you would not be able to modify that 12 either (but you can change `x` to point to something else), so this is a bad idea in general.

Comment: A minor thing - string literals aren't const in C. It's undefined behaviour to try to change them, of course.

Comment: @teppic Thanks - not const as in `const char*` sure; I meant `char* const` in C++ terms I think.

Comment: In C it's just a plain old `char *` :) (well, technically it's probably `char []`)

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler creates a static (constant) string "hello" and lets x point to that, where it doesn't create a static (constant) int.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it is done properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   int *x;
   x = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 8;

   printf("%d \n", *x);
}
```

Comment: +1, but beware that by casting the result of your malloc you're invoking the wrath of the C-tag regulars. (Not that I mind.)

Comment: Better: `int *x = malloc(sizeof *x);`

Comment: Oh, thank you guys, just found out what is up, but here is my source:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/
So they are wrong?

Comment: @GRC cplusplus.com is mostly for c++, not for c - this is one example of the difference between them; [some say](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11972076/509868) it's no good even for c++...

Comment: `malloc` returns pointer to `void` anyway, so there is no need to explicitly cast it. The compiler will do that anyway for any assignable value. It's not exactly wrong, but unnecessary.

Comment: @GRC: C++ does not allow implicit conversions from `void *` to other pointer types, so in C++ you would have to cast the result of `malloc`.  Then again, if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place (use `new` instead, and only if one of the standard container types doesn't meet your needs).

Comment: @JohnBode you are right, I know about new in C++ and that is what confuses hell out of me sometimes :(. People cast pointers all the time in C code :(, plus cplusplus.com is not only place where in K&R which is bible of C they used it all over read chapter 6.6 and you will see.

Comment: @GRC: I understand.  Prior to the 1989 standard, `malloc` returned `char *`, so a cast *was* necessary if you wanted to assign the result to a different pointer type.  Old habits die hard, and older programmers who started with K&R C retained the practice even though it wasn't necessary.  They also wrote a lot of reference manuals, so the practice has been passed on.  In the 21st century, though, the rules should be "don't cast the result of `malloc`" in C and "don't use `malloc`" in C++.

Comment: @JohnBode thank you for explaining, I hope that I did not offend you.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Why can't we assign `int *x=12`? You *can* provided that `12` is a valid memory address which holds an `int`. But with a modern OS specifying a hard memory address is completely wrong (perhaps except embedded code). The usage is typically like this

```
int y = 42;             // simple var
int *x = &y;            // address-of: x is pointer to y
*x = 12;                // write a new value to y
```

This *looks* the same as what you asked, but it is not, because your original declaration assigns the value `12` to `x` the pointer itself, not to `*x` its target.

Q2. Why can't we assign `int *x = "12"`? Because you are trying to assign an incompatible type - a `char` pointer to `int` pointer. `"12"` is a *string literal* which is accessed via a pointer.

Q3. But we can assign `char* x= "hello"`

Putting Q1 and Q2 together, `"hello"` generates a pointer which is assigned to the correct type `char*`.